# Does $E[x_i\mid y_i] = 0 \implies \operatorname{cov}(x_i, y_i) = 0$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, expected-value, covariance

$$E[x_i\mid y_i] = 0 \implies \operatorname{cov}(x_i, y_i) = 0\,?$$

I am wondering if the above statement holds true. The LHS is saying that given any value of $y_i$, the expected value of $x_i$ is zero. This seems to suggest that the 2 have zero covariance. Is this true? If so, then it seems to be true as long as  $E[x_i\mid y_i] = \text{constant}$, where the constant doesn't necessarily have to be zero?

In addition, I believe $E[x_i\mid y_i] = \text{constant} \implies E[x_i] = \text{constant}$, which implies that $x_i$ is independent of $y_i$.

Comment: By definition, $E\left[x_i\right]$ is constant so that answers your second point. For your first point, the key proposition to know is the law of iterated expectations. EDIT: I did not see the statement about independence. See the comment below for a counterexample.

Comment: $X_i$ need not be independent of $Y_i$. Consider the example where $Y_i$ is any nondegenerate RV and $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,Y_i^2)$. Then $\mathbb{E}[X_i\mid Y_i]=0$ but $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are not independent.

Comment: @SangchulLee Good point. But if, say, $X_i$ doesn't follow some distribution with zero mean, $X_i$ and $Y_i$ would be independent?

Comment: Independence is a really strong condition, which in general cannot be deduced just by looking at the conditional first moments.

Answer (score 1):

Let me state it in the form of a proposition: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$
be a probability space. Let $X,Y$ be square-integrable random variables.
If $E[X\mid Y]=0$ (i.e., conditional expectation $E[X\mid\sigma(Y)]=0$),
then $Cov(X,Y)=0$.

Proof: Let $\mu_{x}=E[X]$ and $\mu_{y}=E[Y]$. Let $\mathcal{M}=\sigma(Y)$.
Observe that $\mathcal{M=}\sigma(Y-\mu_{y})$. Now
\begin{eqnarray*}
Cov(X,Y) & = & E\left[(X-\mu_{x})(Y-\mu_{y})\right]\\
 & = & E\left[E\left[(X-\mu_{x})(Y-\mu_{y})\mid\mathcal{M}\right]\right]\\
 & = & E\left[(Y-\mu_{y})E\left[(X-\mu_{x})\mid\mathcal{M}\right]\right]\\
 & = & E[(Y-\mu_{y})(-\mu_{x})]\\
 & = & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Makes sense. I'm not used to thinking in terms of sigma-algebra. Why is $\sigma(Y)  = \sigma(Y - \mu_y)$? Also, conditional expectation is also linear just like regular unconditioned expectation right? e.g., $E[X_1 + \ldots + X_n | Z] = E[X_1 | Z] + \ldots + E[X_n | Z]$?

Comment: $\sigma(Y)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ on $\Omega$ such that  $Y$ is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable. Clearly $Y-\mu_y$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, so $\sigma(Y-\mu_Y) \subseteq \sigma(Y)$.